# Sending data from JavaScript to Mongo through C

Tags: javascript, c, ajax, mongodb, express

I am currently using Express and its built in router functionality to send some data that is collected using a form to my mongodb instance. I would like to expand my project to do some heavy manipulation on the data before it reaches the mongo instance.

As I would like my project to scale to possibly 1,000-10,000 data collections and manipulations per second, I thought that the best idea would be to do the manipulation on the server side in C. I am unsure if 1) this is the best approach and 2) how to even send data from my front-end to the C program?

My initial research shows that I may be able to simple make an AJAX call to the C program; however, I am unable to find anyway of process a received AJAX call in C. Any help regarding the best approach to this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using rabbitmq and it's c based client library for serialization from/to UI or Db